# returning one-item series as a tuple in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that, given my input set, only returns one item from an operation, and I need to dump that item as a single tuple.  Here's the df (code to generate below):

```py
df
              animal  number
location
zoo1           lions      10
zoo1       antelopes      20
zoo2      orangutans     500
zoo1          zebras      30
```

What I'm trying to do is find the location with the absolute highest number of animals, and output it as `('zoo2', 500)`.

Some of the things I've tried, with their output, are:

```py
df.loc[[df['number'].idxmax()], 'number']
location
zoo2    500
```

```py
tuple(df.loc[[df['number'].idxmax()], 'number'])
(500,)
```

I figured out that part of the issue is that the location is an index, so I tried to reset it.  This might be getting me close, but I'm not sure how to break it down further from here:

```py
df.loc[[df['number'].idxmax()], 'number'].reset_index()
  location  number
0     zoo2     500
```

This is also close, but it still isn't quite what I need and also seems needlessly complex for what I'm trying to accomplish (I also tried indexing it with `[0]` at the end, but it didn't change the output):

```py
list(zip(df.loc[[df['number'].idxmax()], 'number'].items()))
[(('zoo2', 500),)]
```

To generate the DF:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['lions', 'antelopes', 'orangutans','zebras'],
                   'location': ['zoo1', 'zoo1', 'zoo2', 'zoo1'],
                       'number': [10, 20, 500, 30]})
df = df.set_index('location')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! The following will give you what you want:

```
tuple(df.loc[[df['number'].idxmax()], 'number'].reset_index().values[0])
```

or, if you wanted to use arrays:

```
arr = df.reset_index().values
tuple(arr[arr.argmax(axis=0)[2], [0, 2]])
```

p.s. there's a typo in your df creation code, missiong `'` before `orangutans`