# Returning a tuple from a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series which is as follows:

```
series = pd.Series([100, 70, 50], index = ['Brazil', 'France', 'UK'])
```

I want to retrieve a tuple from the first row with the label as a string and 100,

```
('Brazil', 100)
```

It's similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419576/returning-one-item-series-as-a-tuple-in-pandas), but because I'm dealing with a list and not a dataframe I haven't managed to make their solution work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html) to list:

```
print (list(series.items()))
[('Brazil', 100), ('France', 70), ('UK', 50)]
```